# Inheritance and methods overriding

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I am making a collision system in C++ with SFML. I have a base **object** class with the following methods :

```
class Object : public sf::CircleShape {
protected:
    bool collision;

    void onCollision();
    void afterCollision();
public:
    bool checkCollision(Object& object);
    bool reactCollision(bool _collision);
};

bool Object::checkCollision(Object& object) {
    //Calcul distance with object and radius    
    bool _collision = (distance <= radius)? true : false;

    this->reactCollision(_collision)
    return _collision;
}

bool Object::reactCollision(bool _collision) {
    //If collision state change compare to previous
    if(_collision != collision) {
        if(_collision) {
            this->onCollision();
        }
        else {
            this->afterCollision();
        }

        collision = _collision;
    }
    return _collision;
}

void Object::onCollision() {
    this->setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
}
void Object::afterCollision() {
    this->setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
}
```

And then a **player** class who implement **object** and overide two methods:

```
class Player : public Object {
protected:
    void onCollision();
    void afterCollision();
};

void Player::onCollision() {
    this->setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);
}
void Player::afterCollision() {
    this->setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
}
```

The problem : **player** use the parent base methods instead of his owns specialized methods. If I implement *reactCollision()* and *checkCollision()* in the player class, it's working but that not the goal.

I would like to modify *onCollision()* in the children's classes of **object** without implementing the same code from *reactCollision()* and *checkCollision()* in the children classes.

Comment: forgot `virtual`?

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of the classes `Object` and `Player`, I'm wondering the same as Matthieu.

Comment: Yep it's work (I wasn't even knowing that), but I prefer avoid virtual

Comment: You can't, that's the point of `virtual`...

Comment: Apparently template can be a solution, anyway I overide other methods without `virtual` before and I don't understand why in this case it's not working

Comment: Please post an [mcve]

Comment: Could you post the code where you're using `Player` methods?